# How to restrict mysql table column to specific value

Tags: mysql, database

I was trying to restrict mySql table column like **device_type** to **android** and **ios**. In table structure i set column **device_type** to enum with values **android** and **ios**. 
But while inserting other like xyz it did not give any error or exception it simply leave column as empty.

Is there any way to restrict column to specific values?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to approach this is using foreign key constraints.  Define a table for device types:

```
create table DeviceTypes (
    DeviceType varchar(255) primary key
);

insert into DeviceTypes(DeviceType)
     select 'android' union all select 'ios';
```

Next, you can add a foreign key constraint to enforce the relationship:

```
alter table t add constraint fk_t_devicetype foreign key (devicetype) references DeviceTypes(DeviceType);
```

Attempts to insert values not in the table will result in an error on the insert.

Note that in other databases, you can do essentially the same thing with a `check` constraint.  However, MySQL does not enforce those.  You can also do essentially the same thing with a trigger, but those can be a maintenance challenge.

This method also makes it easy to add new device types.

Also, I would typically use a synthetic key for this purpose (that is, an auto-incremented id), but that isn't necessary to get the functionality you want.

Comment: With Foreign key its easy to restrict but if i dont want to use foreign key on this column then is there any solution to achieve this?

Comment: @Maverick . . . Another method is using a trigger.